# Get only time in milliseconds in android

Tags: android

I want to check if current time is 00:01AM then do a particular job for that I am trying convert only the time to milliseconds when I do that the I get different milliseconds value for different dates.

I tried this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(getResources().getString(R.string.zerozero)));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(getResources().getString(R.string.one)));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


long alarmtime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long currenttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Log.e("Value", "= " + alarmtime + " " + currenttime);
```

When I do the above: milliseconds for today: it shows **1458066660000** and for tomorrow it is :**1458153060000**

So how to check if current time is 00:01AM or not?

Easy way how to compare current Time with given time..?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're getting "milliseconds since the Unix epoch".

Comment: Yes. I know I given that in milliseconds but the question is how do I compare current time with given time. Say Current time is 00:01 or not ?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis();` won't be of much help if all you want to do is check what time it currently is in 12/24h notation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there's a calendar field for "millisecond of day", but you could use:

```
long millisecondOfDay = 
    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) +
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) +
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)) +
    cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

To get the current time-of-day you could then use:

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

... and then perform the same calculation.

All of this is sensitive to the time zone of the calendar of course, so make sure that's appropriate.

As noted in comments, if you just want to find if it's 00:01, you only need to find the *minute* of day:

```
int minuteOfDay = 
    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) +
    cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Or just check those two fields for equality:

```
if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 0 &&
    cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 1)
{
    ...
}
```

But if this is for an alarm, you may well be better off working out the next occurrence and storing that, then checking whether that time has already passed or not. It's hard to know *exactly* what to advise without a lot more context, but hopefully this has given you enough tools to do the rest yourself...

Comment: Correct. I just want to add that if OP wants to trigger a process matching on an _exact_ millisecond, the process might be skipped on some of the days. Would be better to have a flag that denotes if the process has already run; And check the flag any time between 00:01AM and 00:02AM

Comment: @Kevin: Or just remember "the next time to run" and check that periodically; then it doesn't matter if the phone is off for a few minutes....

Comment: That is the better option, yes. But "I want to check if current time is 00:01AM..." gave me the other impression.

Comment: @Kevin: Have expanded my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare using getTimeInMillis() since the calendar day is changing. Instead, you're better off comparing the Hour and Minute fields (you can also do Second and Millisecond if neccessary).

Something like this:

```
Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(getResources().getString(R.string.zerozero)));
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(getResources().getString(R.string.one)));
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

if(alarmCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == nowCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    && alarmCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == nowCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
{
    //Do something
}
```